# Querying csv files in python like sql

Tags: python, sql, csv

This is apparently a popular interview question.
There are 2 CSV files with dinosaur data. We need to query them to return dinosaurs satisfying a certain condition.

Note - We cannot use additional modules like q, fsql, csvkit etc.

file1.csv:

```
NAME,LEG_LENGTH,DIET
Hadrosaurus,1.2,herbivore
Struthiomimus,0.92,omnivore
Velociraptor,1.0,carnivore
Triceratops,0.87,herbivore
Euoplocephalus,1.6,herbivore
Stegosaurus,1.40,herbivore
Tyrannosaurus Rex,2.5,carnivore
```

file2.csv

```
NAME,STRIDE_LENGTH,STANCE
Euoplocephalus,1.87,quadrupedal
Stegosaurus,1.90,quadrupedal
Tyrannosaurus Rex,5.76,bipedal
Hadrosaurus,1.4,bipedal
Deinonychus,1.21,bipedal
Struthiomimus,1.34,bipedal
Velociraptor,2.72,bipedal
```

using the forumla :
speed = ((STRIDE_LENGTH / LEG_LENGTH) - 1) * SQRT(LEG_LENGTH * g), where g = 9.8 m/s^2

Write a program to read csv files, and print only names of bipedal dinosaurs, sorted by speed from fastest to slowest.

In SQL, this would be simple:

```
select f2.name from
file1 f1 join file2 f2 on f1.name = f2.name
where f1.stance = 'bipedal'
order by (f2.stride_length/f1.leg_length - 1)*pow(f1.leg_length*9.8,0.5) desc
```

How can this be done in python ?

Comment: What are your thoughts? I don't think that knowing that one of us can pass the interview is what you really want.

Comment: @IgorRivin, I know how to do it in sql, and I'd like to know how to solve it in python

Comment: Are you allowed to use pandas?

Comment: You need to write the code that does all of those things. This is too broad for StackOverflow

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, not asking for full-fledged deployment-ready code, even pointers or ideas on where to start would be appreciated

Comment: @milihoosh, you mean pandasql as a wrapper for sql queries?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.read_csv('df_1.csv')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('df_2.csv')

df_comb = df_1.join(df_2.set_index('NAME'), on = 'NAME')
df_comb = df_comb.loc[df_comb.STANCE == 'bipedal']
df_comb['SPEED'] = (df_comb.STRIDE_LENGTH/df_comb.LEG_LENGTH - 1)*pd.Series.pow(df_comb.LEG_LENGTH*9.8,0.5)
df_comb.sort_values('SPEED', ascending = False)
```

Not as clean as SQL!

Answer (score 3):

You can write SQL in python using [pandasql](https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: You can use it like this: `pandasql.sqldf("SELECT * FROM foo;", tables)` where `tables` are the pandas tables that you have read in already.  It works but the SQL support is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
def csvtable(file):     # Read CSV file into 2-D dictionary
    table = {}
    f = open(file)
    columns = f.readline().strip().split(',')       # Get column names
    
    for line in f.readlines():
        values = line.strip().split(',')            # Get current row
        for column,value in zip(columns,values):
            if column == 'NAME':                    # table['TREX'] = {}
                key = value
                table[key] = {}
            else:
                table[key][column] = value          # table['TREX']['LENGTH'] = 10
    
    f.close()
    return table


# READ
try:
    table1 = csvtable('csv1.txt')
    table2 = csvtable('csv2.txt')
except Exception as e:
    print (e)


# JOIN, FILTER & COMPUTE
table3 = {}
for value in table1.keys():
    if value in table2.keys() and table2[value]['STANCE'] == 'bipedal':             # Join both tables on key (NAME) and filter (STANCE)

        leg_length = float(table1[value]['LEG_LENGTH'])
        stride_length = float(table2[value]['STRIDE_LENGTH'])
        speed = ((stride_length / leg_length) - 1) * pow((leg_length * 9.8),0.5)    # Compute SPEED

        table3[value] = speed


# SORT
result = sorted(table3, key=lambda x:table3[x], reverse=True)                       # Sort descending by value

# WRITE
try:
    f = open('result.txt', 'w')
    for r in result:
        f.write('%s\n' % r)
    f.close()
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `duckdb`: https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview

Example:

```
import duckdb
duckdb.sql("""
  SELECT f1.NAME FROM 'file1.csv' as 'f1'
  JOIN 'file2.csv' as 'f2' ON f1.NAME = f2.NAME
  WHERE STANCE = 'bipedal'
  ORDER BY (STRIDE_LENGTH/LEG_LENGTH - 1)*pow(LEG_LENGTH*9.8,0.5) DESC
""")
```

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered the same problem at work and decided to build an offline Desktop app where you can load CSVs and start writing SQL. You can join, group by, and etc.

This is backed by C and SQLite and can handle GBs of CSVs file in ~10 seconds. It's very fast.

Here's the app: https://superintendent.app/

[image: Superintendent.app]

This is not Python though, but it is a lot more convenient to use.